# How to Read texfile etch.. from Application folder where Application is Installed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I Added textfile on my Application Folder where the application is also located.

I having a problem where to locate and read the content of the texfile regarding what location the users specify the application to be installed.

Example:

CASE 1: If Application Installed on C

Get the path of: C:\Textfile.txt

CASE 2:If Application Installed on Program files

Get the path of C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\Textfile.Text

Thanks in Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if this is what you wanted

```
string StartPath = Application.StartupPath; //or what SilverbackNet suggested
string FileName = "YourFileName.txt"

Textreader tr = new StreamReader(StartPath+ "\\" + FileName);

Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());

tr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath` is pretty much the go-to for this particular situation, especially for loading libraries. Please look at `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.*)` for storing data, however, or you'll probably run afowl of stricter permission problems at some point.